# Django AttributeError for CBV object has no attribute 'object'

Tags: python, django

I'm unsure what why I'm getting this error below. I have followed what I assumed to be the correct syntax.

**Error Message:**

AttributeError
    AttributeError: 'CampaignView' object has no attribute 'object'

**Full Trace:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Documents/workspace/test/django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 67, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/user/Documents/workspace/testsite/django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 206, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/Users/user/Documents/workspace/testsite/django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 194, in get_response
    response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
  File "/Users/user/Documents/workspace/testsite/django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 229, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "/Users/user/Documents/workspace/testsite/django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_extensions/management/technical_response.py", line 5, in null_technical_500_response
    six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/user/Documents/workspace/testsite/django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 112, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/Documents/workspace/testsite/django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 69, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/Documents/workspace/testsite/django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 87, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/Documents/workspace/testsite/testsite/apps/campaigns/views/campaign.py", line 54, in post
    return super(CampaignView, self).form_invalid(form)
  File "/Users/user/Documents/workspace/testsite/django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 85, in form_invalid
    return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
  File "/Users/user/Documents/workspace/testsite/django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/detail.py", line 96, in get_context_data
    if self.object:
AttributeError: 'CampaignView' object has no attribute 'object'
```

**View**

```
class CampaignView(UpdateView):
    form_class = UserLookUpFrom
    model = Campaign
    success_url = reverse_lazy('campaigns_detail')




    def form_valid(self, form):
        """
        If the form is valid, in this case DON'T save it!
        """
        return super(CampaignView, self).form_valid(form)

    def _user_exists(self, email_mobile):
        """
        Checks if user exists from email.
        :return: true or false : boolean
        """


        return AppUser.objects.does_user_exists(email_mobile)

    def _get_user_id(self, email_mobile):
        """
        Returns user ID based on email.
        """
        return AppUser.objects.get_user_id(email_mobile)


    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Handles POST requests, instantiating a form instance with the passed
        POST variables and then checked for validity.
        """
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            email_mobile = form.cleaned_data['email_mobile']
            if self._user_exists(email_mobile):
                user_id = self._get_user_id(email_mobile)
                return redirect(reverse('campaigns_share', args=(self.object.id, user_id)))
            return super(CampaignView, self).form_valid(form)
        return super(CampaignView, self).form_invalid(form)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've overridden the `post` method, so a lot of the standard setup that usually happens on a POST will not be called.

Most of the code that you have there - everything inside the `is_valid()` block - would be much better in the `form_valid` method. The rest is covered by the standard behaviour, so you can remove that `post` method altogether.